# How to recover from webusb response status: "babble"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I was testing the new webusb api (https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) on Chrome  and was testing sending (transferOut) and receiving(transferIn) from a USB device.

It worked fine, but I tried reading less data than expected (2 bytes instead of the 3, where the length of the message is actually represented in the two first bytes).

The problem is that when I read less bytes than expected, the USB api returns the status "babble". How do I ensure normal communication after that? I can still send data, but receiving data always returns the error "DOMException: A transfer error has occured."

I tried running device.clearHalt("in", 1) (direction "in" and endpoint 1) but it also doesn't work (throws "DOMException: Unable to clear endpoint.").

Has anyone had this problem yet?

(I'm using Chrome 65.0.3325.181 on OSX)

Comment: I am currently investigating this behavior. Can you file an issue on crbug.com describing the problem?

Comment: For the record, I'm with the exactly same problem but in my case, I need to always read 1 byte at a time, so I'm always doing `transferIn(1, 1)`...

@ReillyGrant can you give us an update on this issue or a least link us with the issue that is handling it?

Thanks

Comment: @gutemberg-ribeiro check ReillyGrant's answer below.
Apparently the best way to solve this is to call transferIn with a length that is a multiple of the endpoints max packet size. Haven't tried it.

Comment: @olivervbk I tried that however, we can't do that in practice... For example, our device always report max==64. So, if I try 2 or 64, I have a big chance of get that call never complete forever because there is no data (that happened here). The API don't resolve the promise and say "hey we didn't have any more data". So, reading per byte makes my case more safe. Otherwise, I'll have to keep managing how much I requested vs how much I received to stop calling that transferIn()... Pretty bad experience...

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro Yeah, I tried passing data byte wise but I gave up and ended up wrapping everything in Protobuf with predefined message formats. AFAICT USB is not designed for single byte communication.

Comment: @olivervbk ok, but I have it working with .Net, byte by byte on the same USB device thru a Serial port...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above I'm still investigating the the best ways to recover from the `babble` error but regardless the easiest way to solve this problem is to avoid calling `transferIn()` with a length that isn't a multiple of the endpoint's maximum packet size. It's much easier to handle the extra data in software than try to recover from a hardware protocol error.